# Boostrap fixed top menu on One Page html5, unfold event on menu item click

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can i set the Bootsrap mobile menu to unfold automatic when a link(anchor on the same page) is clicked.

- The menu unfolded `navbar-collapse collapse in`
- The menu folded is    `navbar-collapse collapse out`

My menu has arleady onlick event:

```
<li><a onclick="return scrollPage('section1')" href="#section1">Contact</a></li>
```

PS: I use Boostrap 3

Comment: Try adding class `.in` to `navbar-collapse collapse` on click of a link. Use `addClass()` method of jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method that's available as part of the collapse plugin (which in required for the standard collapsible menus) - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-methods

So to simply toggle your menu (Open if it's closed, Close if it's open) you can fire this bit of JavaScript (assuming your menu has an id of MyMenu. Any jQuery selector will work here).

```
$('#TheMenu').collapse('toggle');
```

If you want to open your menu, just use

```
$('#TheMenu').collapse('show');
```

And unsurprisingly, to close your menu, just use

```
$('#TheMenu').collapse('hide');
```